# multiple hypothesis tests for features selection (classification)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, model-selection

I am wondering whether running multiple hypothesis tests (t-test / Mann Whitney) as a first step in classification problem.

Specifically: given a data set with *k* features (k=3 in the example bellow), one can run t-test *k* times, using each feature at a time, fine the p-value corresponding to whether the distribution of `feature_i` in class `0` is statistically different than in class `1`. Correct for multiple comparisons and keep only features which p-values 'survived' the correction and are < 0.05. Then, these features will be used in further classification model.

[image]

In this example, I compute two-sample t-test (for class 0 and 1).

Does this procedure make sense at all or it makes more sense to use regularisation to find the best model (features)?

Answer (score 1):

Just throw them all into a random forest. It's quite fast and robust to noisy predictors.

Comment: thanks! I'm actually doing XGBoost classification, however, I observed, that this kind of feature pre-selection my model performed better.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good approach, because it does not consider any interactions between any of the variables, since a t-test is a univariate test, that is checking one variable at a time.

That's what more complex models are better at. Regularization would be a better option then multiple t-tests.